# What is an "IFD size"?

Tags: php, image, exif

What does IFD mean?

I have a error message in my application when I upload an image:

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(upload_file123): Illegal
>   IFD size in
>   /srv/www/path/to/my/vendor/gregwar/image/Gregwar/Image/Adapter/Common.php
>   on line 102

What does this mean? I tried to search in Google, but I couldn’t find what IFD means.

What might be the causes of this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP exif\_read\_data Illegal IFD size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352371/php-exif-read-data-illegal-ifd-size)

Comment: I want to know what is IDF size

Comment: Image File Directory - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif

Comment: @MarkSetchell I believe that your comment is considered an answer- please add an answer instead of a comment... per the section **When shouldn't I comment?** on [_Comment Everywhere_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)